# Liferay 6.2 maven plugin build-css taking long time to parse css from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sass, liferay

Liferay 6.2 maven plugin build-css taking long time to parse css from Jenkins full build.
Same build takes significantly less time when invoked from command line with "mvn clean install" command.

**From Jenkins v1.613 Full Build**

```
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/application.css in 16474 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/aui.css in 39535 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/base.css in 5560 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/custom.css in 12911 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/dockbar.css in 6899 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/extras.css in 8634 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/layout.css in 126 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/main.css in 62007 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/navigation.css in 5947 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/portlet.css in 7052 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/uniform.default.css in 775 ms
```

**From Command line**

```
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/application.css in 11293 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/aui.css in 8813 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/base.css in 649 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/custom.css in 1141 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/dockbar.css in 692 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/extras.css in 1003 ms
Parsed /opt/jenkins_home/workspace/project_name/themes/some-theme/target/some-theme-1.0/css/layout.css in 28 ms
```

Any body know solution to this problem?
We made sure that JenkinsTomcat is not performing garbage collection at that time.

Comment: Please add the information according to [this question and its answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823) to all of your crossposts

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're invoking both executions from the same machine, so that you can discard network problems. If you get so different response times, maybe there are some differences between both executions.
I'd start customizing memory settings for your build process in Jenkins. Have a look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors and see if it helps.

In your case you're building a theme, but the goal "build-css" is also enabled by default for portlets. If you don't plan to include custom css in a portlet, it's a good idea to disable that goal, as it takes a long time.